# Unit tests works locally but does not work on Jenkins

Tags: php, docker, jenkins, build, devops

Been banging my head for hours now. I have just gotten started with Docker, and build systems. I have a PHP Codeception (unit testing framework) codebase as a repo example. Locally, I am able to successfully run the test, but when I check-in my code and it goes to the CI (Jenkins), the client program can be invoked but says no tests found.

***note** *I know that my build definitions could use some work, my goal is just to get a working build.*

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM codeception/codeception
```

**Makefile**

```
APP_NAME=codeception
ROOT_DIR=${PWD}
WORK_DIR=app

    docker_build:
        docker build -t $(APP_NAME) .

    run_test:
        docker run --rm --name ception -w /$(WORK_DIR) -v $(ROOT_DIR):/$(WORK_DIR) $(APP_NAME) run acceptance
```

Just for arguments sake, this is how it prints in the build system

```
docker run --rm --name ception -w /app -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/codeception:/app codeception run
```

**Build Triggers**

```
make docker_build
make run_test
```

**Local Output**

```
OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
```

**Jenkins Output**

*note did not fail, but..

```
no tests executed!
```

**Jenkins Installation**

Host is a Docker machine droplet on digital ocean and I ran a Jenkins container voluming Docker sock so I can invoke Docker on build triggers

---

**ANOTHER QUESTION**

Given the above preconditions with the command:

*note the `pwd`

```
docker run --rm --name ception -w /app -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/codeception:/app codeception run; pwd
```

Jenkins output:

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/codeception
```

I was expecting it to output `/app` because my understanding is, it invokes `pwd` from inside the docker container, so this should have outputed the `/app` directory. I am confused now

**Logs:**

```
Started by GitHub push by edsk3o
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/codeception
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/edsk3o/codeception.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/edsk3o/codeception.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/edsk3o/codeception.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 1a7dd08ef1ed9e8e7b3f236c50690b65c65f37e8 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 1a7dd08ef1ed9e8e7b3f236c50690b65c65f37e8
Commit message: "laksjd"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 528640c7be393aaa06f94edc80f12234a759efd6 # timeout=10
[codeception] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins9213645655529951332.sh
+ make docker_build
docker build -t codeception .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.408MB

Step 1/1 : FROM codeception/codeception
 ---> 1681da57f253
Successfully built 1681da57f253
Successfully tagged codeception:latest
+ make run_test
docker run --rm --name ception -w /app -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/codeception:/app codeception run acceptance; pwd
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.3.8
Powered by PHPUnit 6.5.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

[1mAcceptance Tests (0) [22m---------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 89 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

[30;43mNo tests executed![0m
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/codeception
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Same Docker versions locally and remotely? Have you tried setting set non-essential `-w` and `-v` right in the Dockerfile as `WORKDIR` and `VOLUME`? Also, get into a container manually and check you `/app`. Is you app really there?

Comment: @AlexKarshin I have not tried the directives approach but I entered the container and it appears that `/app` is present: `root@745722112d7e:/app#`

Comment: It should be present since you `-v` it. But if you `ls -la` it, would it have any contents?

Comment: @AlexKarshin just checked.. yes my source code contains it

Comment: My guess the container gets `-w` the wrong way. Anything in the logs? Is it on the right git branch?

Comment: @AlexKarshin same result with `WORKDIR /app` and I believe it is on the correct branch otherwise it would not have triggered.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas :( Maybe logs could provide more info?

Comment: @AlexKarshin I added the logs